# Sync settings contacts on Salesforce for Outlook

Tags: administration

I ma trying to enable Sync Settings Contacts in the tab Salesforce for Outlook.
[image: Salesforce for Outlook Sync Contacts]

I am the admin, and in the tab outlook configurations I have add a new outlook configuration for the user, and I have enable this option in here, like the image below, I just dont understand where else I have to modify to enabling the contacts?

[image: Enabling contacts]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the configuration you are using does not have the contacts sync'ing. You can edit the existing configuration to include contacts or create a new one that syncs the contacts and assign the users who need to sync the contacts to this new configuration. Click [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_config_create.htm&language=en_US) for help creating outlook configurations.